# error con cx_freeze python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estos son mis scripts:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import db
from firebase_admin import credentials
import threading

def login():
    cred = credentials.Certificate("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/fire/New_Firebase.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
            'databaseURL':'https://new1-3b819.firebaseio.com/'
    })
t = threading.Thread(target=login)
t.start()
t.join()
```

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore
from Firebase_load import login


class Inicio(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/Interfaces/Inicio.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        self.minim.clicked.connect(lambda:self.showMinimized())
        self.Maxim.clicked.connect(self.tamano_Principal)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()


    def tamano_Principal(self):
        if self.isMaximized():
            self.showNormal()
        else:
            self.showMaximized()

    def mostrar_hora(self):

        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss  AP"))




#app = QApplication([])
#i = Inicio()
#i.show()
#app.exec_()
```

---

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, Qt
import threading
from Inicio import *
from Firebase_load import *

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("C:/Users/Angel/Desktop/N_Proyect/Interfaces/Login.ui",self)

        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground,True)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground,False)

        self.closed.clicked.connect(lambda:self.close())
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.mostrar_hora)
        t.start()

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.mostrar_hora)
        self.timer.start()

    def mostrar_hora(self):
        self.hora.setText(QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("hh:mm:ss AP"))



class Dato(Principal):
    def __init__(self):
        Principal.__init__(self)
        self.b_login.clicked.connect(self.validate_User)

    def validate_User(self):
        user = self.l_usuario.text()

        if user == '':
            self.l_status.setText('No se ingreso un usuario')
        else:
            ref = db.reference("/usuarios")
            res = ref.get()

            for key in res.items():
                if key[1]['usuario'] == user:
                    ref_pass = key[0] #nombre
                    self.l_status.setText('')
                    self.validate_password(ref_pass)
                    break
                else:
                    self.l_status.setText("El usuario "+ user +" no fue encontrado")
                    break

    def validate_password(self,user):
        password  = self.l_password.text()

        refp = db.reference("/usuarios/"+user)
        res = refp.get()

        for key in res.items():
            if key[0] == 'password':
                if key[1] == password:
                    self.other()
                else:
                    self.l_password.setText('')
                    self.l_status.setText("Invalidate Password")



    def other(self):
        self.close()
        self.inicio = Inicio()
        self.inicio.user.setText(self.l_usuario.text())
        self.inicio.show()

app = QApplication([])
p = Dato()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

**Archivos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución al error es simple solo buscar la ruta donde se ubica el modulo de google dentro de python ejemplo: `C:\Users\Nombre_de_Usuario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\google`, y crear un archivo vacio con el nombre `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

el error que marca el dialogo al fina es No Module Named 'Google', lo que indica que no tienes instalado ese módulo o no tienes activado tu entorno virtual, intenta ejecutar `pip freeze`, para verificar si lo tienes instalado.

Comment: el modulo google si esta instaladop